# SQL Server 2005 Easy way to add all users to a database role

Tags: permissions, sql-server-2005, role, dmv, automation

I have three application databases: A, B and C.

Users of A and B are all users in C; the users from A are in the public role with only SELECT permission, while the users from B are in a role with more permissions.

Due to some recent changes, all of the users on C need to be in the other role and not just public.

Since this will go out as a database patch and be executed automatically on 150+ databases, I would prefer it to be a simple, blanket script...i.e., a single statement that says "put all users in this role".

I know that I can use the script below to create exec statements and loop through the results and execute them, but I'm hoping for something a bit more streamlined.

I've searched around all over the place and can't find anything, but there's always hope for some undocumented system stored procedure that someone knows about.

```
SELECT 'EXECUTE sp_AddRoleMember ''' + roles.name + ''', ''' + users.name + ''''
FROM sys.database_principals users
INNER JOIN sys.database_role_members link 
        ON link.member_principal_id = users.principal_id
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals roles 
        ON roles.principal_id = link.role_principal_id
WHERE roles.name = 'TheNewRole'
```

Comment: Knowing precious little about the security side of things, is it safe to assume you can't just add the users into a domain group and then assign permissions to the group?

Comment: Nope, no domain groups...mix of Windows and SQL Server authenticated users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adam Machanic has a blog post on replacing xp_execresultset which in SQL 2000 did what you want: [Replacing xp_execresultset in SQL Server 2005](http://dataeducation.com/replacing-xp_execresultset-in-sql-server-2005/)

Comment: Thank you, that might just do the trick because I can get it to work with our deployment system.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is originally for sql server 2005, and I am using sql server 2019 just I thought about making it adaptable.

I have a script here that would script out all the users that belong to the `db_tester` role.

This is useful if you want to see all useres that belong to a role, and also if you want to apply the same to a different database (provided all the users are already there).

```
SELECT 'ALTER ROLE [' + roles.name + '] ADD MEMBER [' + users.name + ']' 
FROM sys.database_principals users
INNER JOIN sys.database_role_members link 
        ON link.member_principal_id = users.principal_id
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals roles 
        ON roles.principal_id = link.role_principal_id
WHERE roles.name = 'db_Tester'
```

the result of this (having only one user in that role would be in my server):

[image]

Now if I wanted to add all of the users to this particular role
then I would change the script to:

```
declare @the_role varchar(50) = 'db_test'; --it must exist in the database

  SELECT the_script='ALTER ROLE [' +  @the_role + '] ADD MEMBER [' + users.name + ']' 
FROM sys.database_principals users
where 1=1
  AND users.type in ('S', -- SQL_USER
                     'G', -- WINDOWS_GROUP
                     'U') -- WINDOWS_USER
 AND users.name not in ('dbo','sys','information_schema','guest')
```

this `seems` to be alright, and it has worked for me in a couple of simple small databases, but any I have not tested it extensively.

[another script to list all members of a role](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/113156/22336)